# Android Debug Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

I have imported a project that I worked for so many days, but I had to upgrade the Android Studio, then, I get this error :

```
Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : 
Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Also, When I check my classes I get a red line on every R. and says can not resolve symbol R. 
Do you have Any idea how to fix it?
My android Studio Version is : 2.3.3

build Gradle :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
  }

  allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

 task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "hadirfinal.amjad.hadirfinal"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
 }

    android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
}
```

Comment: try rebuilding your project

Comment: I did. Not working

Comment: did you upgraded the gradle version ?

Comment: what is your current gradle version ?

Comment: Could you provide your gradle script ? Seems there is a conflict.

Comment: check the Gradle Script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check your Java version. The `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` is related to Java 8. Check your JDK in your `SDK Location` from File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location:

[image]

Then upgrade your **root** `build.gradle` with `build:gradle:2.3.3`:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Then update `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, and support library with the same version in your **app** `build.gradle`. Here we use version 25. Then remove the following line `compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'` because you don't need that. So, it will look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 25
   buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

  defaultConfig {
     applicationId "hadirfinal.amjad.hadirfinal"
     minSdkVersion 14
     targetSdkVersion 25
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

android {
   useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
}
```